# sweetalert2 confirm delete when render returning a link in Datatables

Tags: datatables, render, sweetalert2

I am using Datatable and doing my Remove by rendering returning a link. I wanted to do my Remove by confirm with SweetAlert2 however, it was not able to work as expected.

How do I use sweetalert, I cannot assign an id for returning render a link

Comment: The term `datatable` is unclear. Hover your mouse over that tag and read the description. Do you mean the jQuery DataTables library? If so, you should use the `datatables` tag for that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"it was not able to work as expected"_? What actually happened? Any errors? If so, show us those errors (as text). See also [mre]. How can we recreate the problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I do Remove. It omits Confirmation. Do you want to see the full code?

Comment: See the three bullet points at the start of [mre]. Also: any errors in the console? Also: what is `datatable`?

Comment: Just to give you some educated guesses: You are using `Swal.fire` - but the library is `swal` not `Swal`. The function `fire` does not appear to be needed. Just use `swal(...)`. Where is your HTML element with `id="del"`? You are targeting what appears to be a non-existent element: $('#del'). After that, you would probably need to handle the link event, to allow your pop-up event to fire. But these are just guesses, based on the incomplete information I have.

Comment: I am assigning `id = del` to my Action Delete. I tried adding an `id` to it but also with no success

Comment: I posted my code I'm trying below answer

Comment: Please delete your answer - because what you have posted is not an answer. Instead, please [edit] your question and add any relevant details there.

Comment: _"with no success"_ - OK - but what about all the other points I mentioned? You need to fix all the problems, not just one problem.

Comment: I have updated the question and deleted the answer

Comment: The problem is I cannot fix it, I tried a few ways but can't use SweetAlert

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are getting stuck.

Here is my version:

I am using SweetAlert 2:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.15.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

I have the following render function in my DataTable:

```
{
  render: function (data) {
    return '<a id="del" href="/your/example/here/' + data + '">Remove</a>';
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version of your code, just as a demonstration.

I have the following click handler:

```
$('#del').on('click', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); // don't forget to prevent the default event
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
      )
    }
  });
});
```

This generates a table with links.

When I click on any link, I get the following pop-up alert:

[image]

I have not handled anything relating to actually using the link to delete a resource. I leave that up to you, as a follow-on task, after you get the alert working.

---

You did not really explain what the *specific* problem is that you are facing, except to say "it's not working".

If you have new, additional, problems after this then you can open a new question - but please try to provide sufficient details, including error messages from your browser's console and an easy-to-recreate problem description with related code.

Comment: I tried this before, it really has no bugs, it just ignores the SweetAlert I am using and does Remove. Does it matter if I use `<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "sweetalert2 / dist / sweetalert2.min.css" />` at `_Layout`?

Comment: The code in your question is not the same as the code in my answer.

Comment: I have tried your code, and I am trying a few more. It still ignores SweetAlert

Comment: In that case you need to provide a [mre].

Comment: I see a warning at Swal "Unresolved variable or type Swal"

Comment: A warning? Or an error? Either way, that suggests you have simply not included the SweetAlert library correctly in your web page. Here is my MRE showing my code working: https://jsfiddle.net/ukdbxmpw/ . Apart from that, maybe you should go back to the Swal tutorials and build the simplest alert you can possibly build, in a basic web page. That way you will know if you have imported the library correctly, or not. I think there is nothing more I can do to help you, given the information you have provided. I hope you are able to work it out. I wish you good luck.

Comment: I will try, thanks for what you helped me